# Programatically reset all camera_input / file_uploader

Tags: python, streamlit

#### Summary

I need to be able to clear the photos uploaded either using camera_input or file_uploader programatically via python.

I saw this other post: [How to Clear uploaded images when using st.file_uploader, accepting multiple files and how to clear other outputs? - ☁️ Streamlit Community Cloud - Streamlit](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-clear-uploaded-images-when-using-st-file-uploader-accepting-multiple-files-and-how-to-clear-other-outputs/33123). However it does not apply to me because I need to be able to perform different action depending on the photos uploaded. One of them being to clear all uploaded photos and retake.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
import streamlit as st

st.camera_input("Photo 1", key="photo1")
st.camera_input("Photo 2", key="photo2")
st.camera_input("Photo 3", key="photo3")

st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo4")
st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo5")
st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo6")


if st.button("Clear Photos"):
    st.session_state.pop("photo1")
    st.session_state.pop("photo2")
    st.session_state.pop("photo3")
    st.session_state.pop("photo4")
    st.session_state.pop("photo5")
    st.session_state.pop("photo6")
    st.session_state.photo1 = None
    st.session_state.photo2 = None
    st.session_state.photo3 = None
    st.session_state.photo4 = None
    st.session_state.photo5 = None
    st.session_state.photo6 = None

st.session_state
```

**Expected behavior:**

Reset all photos uploaded using both camera_input and file_uploaded. Including resetting the widget itself to its clean slate.

**Actual behavior:**

Although the st.session_state is reset, the widget is still displayed in it's state before I change the session_state

[image]
[image]

#### Alternative Method tested

Alternative i tried to make use of st.empty(). Code as follows:

```
import streamlit as st

placeholder = st.empty()

with placeholder.container():
    st.camera_input("Photo 1", key="photo1")
    st.camera_input("Photo 2", key="photo2")
    st.camera_input("Photo 3", key="photo3")
    st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo4")
    st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo5")
    st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo6")


if st.button("Clear Photos"):
    placeholder.empty()
    for key, value in st.session_state.items():
        if "photo" in key:
            st.session_state.pop(key)

    st.session_state

    with placeholder.container():
        st.camera_input("Photo 1", key="photo1")
        st.camera_input("Photo 2", key="photo2")
        st.camera_input("Photo 3", key="photo3")
        st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo4")
        st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo5")
        st.file_uploader("Upload your photos", key="photo6")
```

However i run into another error as follows:

**DuplicateWidgetID**: There are multiple widgets with the same `key='photo1'`.

To fix this, please make sure that the `key` argument is unique for each widget you create.

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\work\test\app.py", line 23, in <module>
    st.camera_input("Photo 1", key="photo1")
```

#### Debug info

- Streamlit version: 1.21.0
- Python version: 3.9.16